# Studying web servers such as apache httpd and tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, open-source

I would like to see how everything is handled behind the scenes behind web servers such as apache httpd and tomcat. How does one go about stepping through these applications, making changes, and then viewing changes?? Applications this complex use scripts for building and I presume they take a while to compile, it seems to me that there would be more to it than simply downloading the source code and importing into Eclipse. Or is it actually that simple?

And how do developers who want to work on the code of these projects get around the fact that it will take a fair amount of time to compile these applications (and other non-trivial applications such as web browsers)? When I am working on smaller stuff I am constantly compiling and then debugging. I imagine that is no feasible when it can take several minutes to compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy: just read.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/building.html

Also, http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing

The current Tomcat 7.0.x trunk takes about 17 seconds to build on my MacBook Pro, and that included downloading a few dependencies that I didn't already have laying around. If you want to re-compile a single .java file, you can re-run the entire build and the toolchain (really just Apache Ant) will figure out which files actually need to be recompiled.

You only modified one source file? Only one source file will be re-compiled when you run `ant deploy` (you don't even need the "deploy": it's the default). If you use Eclipse or some other similar IDE, it will recompile on the fly and you don't need to worry about the command line or any of that.

If you have further questions, please join the Tomcat users' mailing list (or the developers' list) and join the community.